# How to extract information from a string in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a csv file containing a awards column with various different nominations and awards won. I want to extract data from the awards column in this `dataset` and split it into several columns. The awards has details of wins, nominations in general and also wins and nominations in certain categories(e.g. Oscar, BAFTA etc.) A sample input of awards column is shown below.

[image: Click here for Input image]

And I want to split this data into several columns analyzing the data. Can we achieve this using python? I am using pandas for accessing `dataframe`. A sample expected output is shown below.

[image: Click here for Output image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.  Also, please post you data and not an image of your data.

Comment: I am a newbie in python, I am starting from scratch so basically have got no idea.

Comment: Don't know the best way but can be done by making cases of different patterns.

Comment: @user3473754 "I am a newbie in Python, I am starting from scratch so basically have got no idea." Read more books, do more tutorials, and take a look at various docs for modules like `csv` and `pandas`. And if you have problem with your implementation, come back to us. Thanks.

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin Everyone has to start somewhere at some point of time and everyone needs help. If you are this smart can you solve this problem? That would be more appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: @user3473754 "If you are this smart" I never said I am smart. It was an honest attempt at helping you so you might wanna read that again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your data are not particularly well structured. If the format was guaranteed to be in the form:

> *x* wins & *y* nominations.

Then the following code:

```
testStrings = ['1 win & 1 nomination.','2 wins.','5 nominations.', '3 wins & 8 nominations.', '2 wins.','9 wins.']

text = [i.split('&') for i in testStrings]

data=[]
for row in text:
    for t in row:
        winIndex = t.find('win')
        nomIndex = t.find('nom')
        if winIndex>0:
            w=int(t[:winIndex-1] )
        else:
            w=0
        if nomIndex>0:
            n=int(t[:nomIndex-1] )
        else:
            n=0
    data.append([w,n])
```

Will give you the list **data** where each element is *[numWins, numNoms]* for each row.

You can probably extend this to cope with different formats (e.g. "Won 1 Primetime Emmy"), by searching for those keywords (like the code looks for the substrings "won" and "nom"). Hope this provides some help.

Comment: That's the problem data is in unstructured format. Is there any way I can make it structured?

Comment: Do you mean your input data is unstructured? Or the output?

Comment: Input is unstructured. The way column is shown in the image.